# How to add more <div></div> tags into svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

just wondering, if there is a button function to create and add/remove  tags into/from svg??

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes, something like `$('#button').click(function() { $('#svg').append($('<div/>')); });`

Comment: how about if i add in image into that div?

Comment: then you do `var div = $('<div/>'); var img = $('<img/>', {src: '/path/to/image'}); div.append(img);`

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
 $('#button').click(function() { 
       var permalink = $("#image_file_input_field").val(); 
       $('#svg').html("<div><img src=" + permalink + "></div>');
});
```

Comment: May i know what does this line mean? [#image_file_input_field] Thanks for the help..

Comment: you should look at javascript and javascript libraries like jquery, modjo etc...SVG is markup language based on xml so you can use javascript to make dynamical modification to it